# A User with many Addresses, but User has a primary billing, shipping, and profile Address

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database-design, has-many-through

I'm building a Rails app where a `User` can have many `Addresses`. A `User` also needs a primary billing `Address`, primary shipping `Address`, and primary profile `Address`. These primary fields can point to the same `Address`. A `User` cannot have more than one of any primary `Address`.

I've created a join table called `AddressInfo`, and I'm bouncing between a few options:

1. Make 3 columns on the `User` model corresponding to each of the primary `Address` ids (this would remove the need for the join model I think).
2. Add a `primary` boolean column to `AddressInfo`, and make sure only one is true when scoped by `user_id`, `address_id` and `purpose` (purpose being `billing`, `shipping` or `profile`).
3. Add a `primary` date time column to `AddressInfo`, and use the most recently updated as the primary address (scoped like option 2).

Maybe these options aren't the best, but it's what I've come up with so far.

Any help on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

To be clear, once an `Address` is created it should always belong to that `User` and be undeletable. Ex. a `User` changes their primary billing address to a new `Address`: they should still be able to retrieve that old `Address` (maybe even make it a primary address again). If I go with option 1 and remove the join table, that means I'll need a `user_id` on `Address`.

Comment: Any thoughts on my answer?  The example I found at: http://blog.arkency.com/2013/07/sti/ seemed close to your requirements. :)

Answer (score 1):

Go with option 1, 3 columns.  This will make less of a headache (as a programmer), will run faster, and is more flexible for doing things like combining similar addresses into one.  Maybe you have 2 people with the same address, they could share the same record (not recomeneded though).

Comment: +1, but I disagree that the join model should be dispensed with. You can keep it in there and just use the primary address id's effectively as filters against it to identify the join table record that represents the primary address of a particular type. Doing without the join table limits the number of addresses to a maximum of three, which might not be desirable.

Comment: @DavidAldridge Right. Just updated my OP to mention that I do want to keep track of every `Address`, primary or not. If I got rid of the join model, then I'd have to add `user_id` to `Address`.

Comment: With the new info in your update, you should go with option 3, option 1 isn't a valid option any longer.  With option 2, trying to handle the flag on only one record requires more updates, selects and is a pain in the *&*%$^%*&.  Option 3 is simple and gives you a date you can follow back to order the history as well. Problem is, you may have multiple "Active" addresses. You should add another field for "Active" as well.

Comment: @Steve I think what you're calling "Active" addresses we call "Displayable". i.e. have a flag on `Address` called `visible` that hides addresses from the user when they "delete" them on the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using rails I would look to a rails solution to 'stay on the rails'.

I would consider STI ([Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html))
More info at [Rails: Need help defining association for address table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353317/rails-need-help-defining-association-for-address-table)

or a Polymorphic relationship - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

As you want 1 user to have multiple address (rather than ther being multiple user types) than STI may be best for you.

Note: they can also be combined, e.g. http://www.archonsystems.com/devblog/2011/12/20/rails-single-table-inheritance-with-polymorphic-association/

There's a great example of STI addressing this issue at: http://blog.arkency.com/2013/07/sti/

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to create another model to hold user.id, addressinfo.id, and an primary_for_address_type (containing "Shipping", "Profile", "Billing").

Constrain this to be unique on user and primary_for_address_type, and you can tag addresses in AddressInfo as being the primary for particular address types in a completely extensible way that still guarantees uniqueness of the primary address.

You might join directly from this model to address, but there's scope for getting it out of sync with your addressinfo model.